# For loop reading a file isn't working

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
private void getAccount()
{
    string[] acct = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Accts.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < acct[line].Length - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (char c in acct[line])
        {
            if (c.ToString() == ":")
            {
                onPass = true;
                i += 1;
            }
            if (onPass == false) { user += acct[line][i]; }
            if (onPass == true) { pass += acct[line][i]; }
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Username is " + user + ". \n\nPassword is " + pass + ".");
    onPass = false;
}
```

The file has this:

```
minicl55:mypass
```

However this outputs this:

[image]

These are the following problems:

- The characters are repeated a lot
- only "mmmmmmm" is considered part of the username, everything up until the colon should be part of the username, after is pass
- The : is included in the password, it should be ignored completely (except to tell where the username stops and the password starts)

Comment: the for loop should begin from 0 and go till (line-1) assuming lines are the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Why don't you simply take desired line iterate over it? `for` is not needed here. Oh, and here, why chars are repeated: `i` won't increase unless `foreach` loop ends, so the same char is appended.

Comment: use two counter variables `i and j'... the first for loop should traverse each line of the file linewise while the second foreach loop with counter j should traverse the contents of each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you go through your `for` loop, `i == 0`. Then the `foreach` loop looks at each character in `acct[line]`, but `i` never changes, so for all the characters prior to `:`, the `acct[line][i]` part keeps returning `acct[line][0]`, or `"m"` 8 times. That's why the username appears to be `"mmmmmmmm"`.

Then the colon is encountered and `i` is increased by 1. Now `onPass == true`, so `pass` ends up having `acct[line][1]`, which is the character `"i"`. This repeats for the rest of the string, so pass appears to be `"iiiiiii"` (from the colon to the end).

Now we go back to the `for` loop. Except `i` has been increased by `1` *inside* the loop (bad idea) so now the `for` loop is actually on `i == 2`. Again the beginning part executes 8 times (once for each character in the username), but always refers to `acct[line][2]`, so the username is `"nnnnnnnn"`. Except `onPass` is still true, so it gets appended to the password variable. Then you get 7 more `"i"`'s after `i` is increased.

The `i` variable is increased internally and in the `for` loop again, so next time you're using `acct[line][4]`, which is `"c"` (8 times), then `i` is increased by 1 inside the `foreach` loop and you get `acct[line][5]` 7 times, which is `"l"`.

So far, password is `"iiiiiiinnnnnnnniiiiiiicccccccclllllll"`. Hopefully you can see the pattern.

---

You could eliminate some of the looping and complexity, and just use something like: *(untested)*

```
private void getAccount()
{
    var allAccounts = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Accts.txt");

    foreach (var account in allAccounts)
    {
        var pieces = account.Split(':');

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Username is {0}. \n\nPassword is {1}.", pieces[0], pieces[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as you're rewriting the whole thing, it's probably better to use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` because that enumerates lines as they're read in instead of reading the whole file into an array. You also want to pass `2` as the second parameter to `Split` so that a password can contain a `:` character.

Answer (score 2):

Your outer loop is iterating over each `char` in `acct[line]`. Then you do the same in your inner loop, you just express it a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

Please show your variables, but here's another approach:

```
       private void getAccount()
        {
            string user = "";
            string pass = "";
            string[] user_pass = new string[0];

            var accts = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Accts.txt");


            foreach(var acct in accts)
            {
                user_pass = acct.Split(':');
            }


            //Add iteration for multiple lines
            if (user_pass.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username is " + user_pass[0] + ". \n\nPassword is " + user_pass[1] + ".");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Chaos: Dogs and Cats Living Together!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see your first loop gets the length of a specific line whose position doesnt change at all.

```
for (int i = 0; i < acct[line].Length - 1; i++)
```

And then you loop through every character of that only line

```
foreach (char c in acct[line])
```

The thing is that if your acct[line] has X length, you will loop through the acct[line] X times, hence why the repeated characters. You end up reading the same character X times.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has commented/answered, your outer and inner loops are pretty much doing the exact same thing. I rewrote the for-loops so the outer loop loops through each line of the array of strings, and then the inside loop will go through all of the characters in that line.

```
            for (int line = 0; line < acct.Length; line++)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (char c in acct[line])
                {
                    if (c.ToString() == ":")
                    {
                        onPass = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!onPass)
                            user += acct[line][i];
                        else
                            pass += acct[line][i];
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

I do suggest however, for your own benefit, if you do NEED to loop through all of the characters to use this for the inner loop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < acct[line].Length; i++)
            {
                if (acct[line][i].ToString() == ":")
                {
                    onPass = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!onPass)
                        user += acct[line][i];
                    else
                        pass += acct[line][i];
                }
            }
```

Or better yet replace everything with something simpler, and less prone to being broken by small changes:

```
        for (int line = 0; line < acct.Length; line++)
        {
            if (acct[line].Contains(":"))
            {
                string[] parts = acct[line].Split(':');
                user = parts[0];
                pass = parts[1];
                MessageBox.Show("Username is " + user + ". \n\nPassword is " + pass + ".");
            }
        }
```